# Authentication and URL-shortener Node js app problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, url, ejs

The provided code contains 2 separate applications. What I'm trying to do is build an app where the login page is first loaded when the app runs, and then upon successful authentication, it redirects the user to the index.ejs page. when index.ejs page is loaded I want the app to run the url-shortener part. I'm still very new to node js but still would like to finish this app. I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("./passport");

const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");

initializePassport(
  passport,
  (email) => users.find((user) => user.email === email),
  (id) => users.find((user) => user.id === id)
);

const users = [];

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// route for login page
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

// route for register page
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});

// login post
app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/index.ejs",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);
// register post
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    res.redirect("/login");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect("/register");
  }
});

// route for home page
app.get("/index", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

//url shortenr
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ShortUrl = require("./models/shortUrl");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/urlShortener", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find();
  res.render("index", { shortUrls: shortUrls });
});

app.post("/shortUrls", async (req, res) => {
  await ShortUrl.create({ full: req.body.fullUrl });

  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/:shortUrl", async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrl = await ShortUrl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl });
  if (shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404);

  shortUrl.save();

  res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your code that combines authentication and URL shortening in the way you described:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {


require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("./passport");

const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");

initializePassport(
  passport,
  (email) => users.find((user) => user.email === email),
  (id) => users.find((user) => user.id === id)
);

const users = [];

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// route for login page
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

// route for register page
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});

// login post
app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/index", // Redirect to index after successful login
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);

// register post
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    res.redirect("/login");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect("/register");
  }
});

// Middleware to ensure the user is authenticated before accessing /index
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/login");
}

// route for home page (index.ejs)
app.get("/index", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

// URL shortener routes
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ShortUrl = require("./models/shortUrl");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/urlShortener", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find();
  res.render("index", { shortUrls: shortUrls });
});

app.post("/shortUrls", async (req, res) => {
  await ShortUrl.create({ full: req.body.fullUrl });
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/:shortUrl", async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrl = await ShortUrl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl });
  if (shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404);

  shortUrl.save();

  res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still receiving the error "This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.". I've tried changing the port number, and checked firewalls and everything, but it's still not working.